# Como Quitar el titulo del proyecto en el Main

Tags: android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado trabajando en una App ya practicamente lo estoy acabando, pero quiero quitar esa parte del nombre del proyecto

Comment: ¿Te refieres a quitar el toolbar o solo el texto y dejarlo vacío?
https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/?hl=es-419

Comment: solo el texto hermano

Comment: @JorgeCarrascoToledo Agrega tu layout porque probablemente estes usando un Toolbar, trata des agregar detalles para poder ayudarte con exactitud, revisa [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, pero una de ellas sería llamar **setDisplayShowTitleEnabled** dentro del método **onCreate** tu activity después de llamar **setContentView(...)**.

Si tu Activity desciende de [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

O si desciende de [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity):

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si se trata solo del Texto puedes setear un String Vacio al Toolbar.
Suponiendo que tienes definido el Toolbar en tu ActivityMain.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mi_perfil);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Podria usar esto en tu activity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    }
```

**WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN** Esta sentencia hara que el layout ocupe todo tu pantalla, osea se ocultara la barra notificaciones, si solo quieres eliminar el titulo no coloques esta sentencia.

**requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)**, Esta sentencia es la que ocultara el titulo de tu activity.